# How does comparator function of c++ STL sort work?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

```
bool sortbysec(const pair<int,int> &a,const pair<int,int> &b) 
{ 
    return (a.second < b.second); 
} 
  

sort(vect.begin(), vect.end(), sortbysec);

vector< pair <int, int> > vect; 
  
int arr[] = {10, 17, 5, 70 }; 
int arr1[] = {30, 60, 20, 50}; 
int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); 
  
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    vect.push_back( make_pair(arr[i],arr1[i]));
```

what does return(a.second<b.second) mean?
how is it sorting by the second element?

Comment: By default the C++ tries whether std::less is applicable, if so, you don't have to use a compare function. Also if you use object for which `bool operator <()`  is implemented stl::sort can also use less. Note that the operator bool should have absolute ordering.

Answer (score 7):

The concept of a sorted sequence `s`, in abstract, is that for any pair of elements `s[i]` and `s[j]`, `s[i]` is not greater than `s[j]` when `i` is less than `j`.

Sorting a sequence is simply rearranging the elements of the sequence to satisfy this definition.  Therefore, in order to sort elements, we need to be able to ask if a particular value is less than or greater than some other value -- otherwise we cannot be sure that our arrangement of the sequence satisfies the definition of a "sorted sequence."

`std::sort` takes a *comparison function* as a means of answering this question.  By default, it is `std::less<T>()` which simply uses the operator `<` to compare two elements.  By applying this function to two elements, it can determine if they need to be rearranged.  Looking at our definition of a sorted sequence, if `s[j] < s[i]` when `i < j` then the definition is not met.  Swapping those two elements corrects the problem for that specific pair of elements.

By applying this comparison function along with a *sorting algorithm,* `std::sort` is able to determine the order that the elements should be in for the sequence to be sorted.  That's all the sort function does: it applies this comparison function to pairs of elements and rearranges them until the sequence is sorted.

You can supply any comparison function `fn` that has [strict weak ordering](https://www.boost.org/sgi/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) and `std::sort` will rearrange the elements as necessary to ensure that `!fn(s[i], s[j])` is true for all valid index pairs `i` and `j` where `i > j`.  This allows you to manipulate the sort function to get specific orders.  For example:

- If you supply a function that compares using the `>` operator instead of the `<` operator, then the sorted sequence will be in descending order.
- You can supply a function that compares a specific attribute of the values.  If you have a sequence of `struct Person { std::string name; int age; }` values, you could have a function that compares the ages only, which will sort the sequence by the age attribute.

  - You could even sort on multiple attributes.  If you compare `age` first and then compare `name` if the ages are equal, the sequence will be sorted by age -- but within each subsequence where the age is equal, that subsequence is sorted by name.

Comment: You could have provided examples, instead of just theory for a better explanation.